Meat, nature and the Torah
What is the effect of eating little meat or a lot of meat on the body, spirit, soul according to the Torah? Since I eat a LOT of red meat, my life has completely changed, I feel extremely strong and happy like many many many other people and I find it extremely strange that G-d didn't talk about this when health is the base of life.
Why does the Torah say "By the sweat of your face you shall eat bread" when that is only the case for farmer societies? Hunter gatherers live an extremely easy and happy life. Hunting and gathering is extremely fun and easy. Reality contradicts the Torah?

You should consider replacing the meat with another protein and see if you still feel strong. It could be that its something else in your diet that was causing you to feel weak, such as excessive low-grade carbs. Perhaps you have a tendency towards diabetes or something. Eating huge amounts of meats is very controversial among doctors, with many still saying it's a very dangerous thing to do.

According to Rashi (Bava Kamma 72a), "eating beef" is used as a metaphor for clear thinking:דלא אכלי בשרא דתורא - לא דקדקתי טעמו של דבר

The word translated here as "bread" - לחם. - can also mean "food," generically. I'm not sure that that verse's scope is necessarily restricted to framing societies.

The Torah doesn't really give medical advice. If eating meat works for you, great.

Excess protein can cause gout

Thanks for your replies. @RabbiKaii beef in particular gives me this effect. I came to the conclusion that it comes from the aminoacids creatine & carnitine as I've tried those as supplements. I am not a believer but the difference is so insane that I find it very strange that there is nothing in the jewish religion talking about it. It changes your life in every aspect to a very very strong extent. It also changes how you feel in terms of spirituality

The Torah considers meat a luxury food. See Rashi to Devarim 13:20.
